# Nginx Proxy Manager with domain with port to be forwarded

Tags: nginx, proxy-server

On my QNAP TS-673A, i have installed the following docker image jlesage/nginx-proxy-manager , in the NPM web interface under SSL Certificates, i have added my subdomain : cloud.domain.com.
On my registrar the pass.domain.com is linked to the IPWAN of my router which doesn’t change, on my router i have two ports redirected :

```
16895 => 192.168.0.227:443
16896 => 192.168.0.226:443
```

On my router the port 443 is already used by the user portal so i no others choices to use the ports 16895 and 16896
On NPM how to make the rule proxy to https://pass.domain.com: 16896 forwaded to 192.168.0.226:443

On my QNAP TS-673A the network map is the following :
[image]

It seems it doesn't go by the NPM, what i have missed ?

Comment: I have switched to Nginx Proxy Manager so i can close this one